# Android Studio Kotlin: Extract as Constant

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, extract, constants

In IntelliJ-based IDEs like Android Studio, in **Java** source codes, there is an option to extract things as **constants** when possible (`final static`). It is in `Refactor -> Extract -> Constant` and is accessible via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

But I can't find it for **Kotlin** source codes!

[image]

---

Note 1: I can do it *manually* as you can see about `NUMBER` in the above screenshot (by defining it as a `const val` in `companion object`).

Note 2: The reverse-action is accomplishable by IDE; it means you can inline `NUMBER` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known missing feature for now. It's being tracked on [the official issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11050). You can vote for it there =)